# Eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker is not working

Tags: model-view-controller, layout, view

In my _Layout view I have this as scripts (also CSS have been added):

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/js/morris-data.js"></script>
        <!-- Moment -->
        <script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <!-- DateTimePicker -->
        <script src="/Content/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
       
       
        <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src="/Content/themes/sb-admin-2/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({


            sideBySide: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

And also, in my view where I want to show the datetimepicker I have this:

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Publish Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PublishDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker", placeholder = "Date", required = "required" })
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I tried many things to show the datetimepicker, have someone an idea of my problem? I don't have errors thrown in Console, I tried to debug but I didnt find nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div has id="datetimepicker" but you are using selector for class ".datetimepicker".
Try to change:

> $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
>              sideBySide: true
>          });

into

> $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
>              sideBySide: true
>          });